# Item Response Theory - Calculations with and between Latent Trait Scores

Tags: item-response-theory

After conducting an exploratory IRT analysis, the most suitable theoretical and numerical solution suggests the utilization of five latent traits. These latent traits stem from 18 items, all measured on an ordinal Likert scale ranging from 1 to 7. Upon interpreting the resulting latent traits and their relationships with the original items, it appears that there exists a pair of opposing poles. For instance, one pair might represent concepts such as representative democracy (trait 1) and direct democracy (trait 2).

My question revolves around the potential violation of results if I were to subtract the scores between latent traits 1 and 2 for each individual. My conception is that individuals scoring high or low on both opposing pairs of concepts should yield a value close to zero on a reduced single dimension.

My concern is whether the scales of the thetas for each latent trait differ, leading to the scenario where subtracting a value of 3 (from trait 2) from a value of 3 (from trait 1) does not equate to 0, which ideally represents the midpoint on a single dimension. Similarly, if a respondent possesses a high score on direct democracy and a low score on representative democracy, they should receive a negative value on the reduced dimension (indicating a preference toward direct democracy), while positive values would signify a preference toward representative democracy.

I want to reduce dimensions in order to create broader idealtype categories among respondents for a downstream analysis, and this is in my case easier with less dimensions.

Comment: This doesn't address you entire question, but I have doubts about using IRT for your subject.  Discrimination may apply, but how could  difficulty and guessing parameters?  Preferences do not have correct or incorrect answers.